# Localnet on computer not confirming transactions

Tags: testing

After starting a localnet on my computer, I simply am trying to fund the default account, but keep getting errors when it comes to using solana airdrop & other commands. This wasn't happening just yesterday and I am worried something small changed that is causing the issue.

```
    Requesting airdrop of 10 SOL 
    
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds
```

I realized it's such a banal question, but would appreciate any insight since I can't identify anything that change from yesterday's workflow.

Comment: A code example would be good - does the error occur during the airdrop? After the airdrop during a transfer? etc.

Comment: it's not really possible to offer advice on this question as posed.  you need to at least provide the steps you're taking to start your local cluster

Comment: You're correct, but someone was still able to help, and I'm grateful. It was occuring during the airdrop... stuff that was working just fine hours ago. All good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your local `solana` cli settings with:

```
solana config get
```

You should see something like:

```
Config File: /Users/user/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/user/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

Verify the RPC URL is pointing to local. A RPC that uses mainnet-beta would not confirm airdrops.

If that doesn't work, try restarting your local-test-validator

```
solana-test-validator
```

and then airdrop directly using it with

```
solana airdrop 1 --url http://localhost:8899
```

Comment: Thank you for this... the direct airdrop worked. Still no clue why 'solana account <default account Pubkey> wasnt't working until I did this directly. Thanks a ton...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running through the Solana Test Validator steps seen here: https://docs.solana.com/developing/test-validator.

The ['check the wallet balance' section](https://docs.solana.com/developing/test-validator#check-the-wallet-balance) might be helpful.